# Mapping one property in JSON using Automapper or Dapper? On which layer?

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core, architecture, clean-architecture

TL;DR:
Which approach with deserializing **one** JSON property would be *the purest*?

- While fetching data from DB, using dapper multimap
- While manual assignment, in service (or in some separate factory)
- With automapper and MapFrom,  in service

---

Long story:
Considering following design in DB:

| Id | Name | Type | JSONAttributes |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | "Foo" | "Red" | `{"Attr11":"Val11", "Attr12" : "Val12" }` |
| 2 | "Bar" | "Green" | `{"Attr21":"Val21", "Attr22" : "Val22" }` |
| 3 | "Baz" | "Blue" | `{"Attr31":"Val31", "Attr32" : "Val32" }` |

Every type has it's own attributes kept in last column in JSON string. The type is not returned by the procedure btw.
I need to transfer this data way up to the controller. I have onion (I believe) solution structure:
MyProject. Web (with controllers)
MyProject. Core (with services, DTOs, entities, interfaces)
MyProject. Data (with repositories, using Dapper)
... and others, not significant to this topic.

Also I have created the models to map these rows to. One abstract, generic and several derived:

```
namespace MyProject.Core.DTO.Details  
{
    public abstract class DtoItem  
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }  
        public string Name { get; set; }  
    }
}
```

```
namespace MyProject.Core.DTO.Details
{
    public class DtoTypeRed : DtoItem
    {
        public DtoTypeRedAttributes AttributesJson { get; set; }
    }
}
```

```
namespace MyProject.Core.DTO.Details
{
    public class DtoTypeGreen : DtoItem
    {
        public DtoTypeGreenAttributes AttributesJson { get; set; }
    }
}
```

```
namespace MyProject.Core.DTO.Details
{
    public class DtoTypeRedAttributes 
    {
        [JsonPropertyName("Attr11")]
        public string AttributeOneOne{ get; set; }
        [JsonPropertyName("Attr12")]
        public string AttributeOneTwo{ get; set; }
    }
}
```

Also created entity, but only used in Option 2 (described later):

```
namespace MyProject.Core.Entities
{
    public class Item
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string AttributesJson { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**My question is, what would be a better approach:**
Option 1 - mapping to the DTO directly, in ItemRepository, in MyProject.Data, when fetching the data from the DB using Dapper multimap, like:

```
namespace MyProject.Data
{
    public class DetailsRepository : IDetailsRepository
    {
        public async Task<DtoItem> GetDetails(int itemId, int itemTypeId)
        {
            using (var connection = _dataAccess.GetConnection())
            {
                switch (itemTypeId)
                {
                    case 1:
                        return (await connection.QueryAsync<DtoTypeRed,string,DtoTypeRed>("[spGetDetails]", (redDetails, redDetailsAttributesJson) =>
                            {
                                redDetails.AttributesJson = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<DtoTypeRed>>(redDetailsAttributesJson).FirstOrDefault();
                                return redDetails;
                            },
                            splitOn: "AttributesJson",
                            param: new { itemId ,itemTypeId},
                            commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure)).FirstOrDefault();
                    case 2:
                        return (await connection.QueryAsync<DtoTypeGreen,string,DtoTypeGreen>("[spGetDetails]", (greenDetails, greenDetailsAttributesJson) =>
                            {
                                greenDetails.AttributesJson = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<DtoTypeGreen>>(greenDetailsAttributesJson).FirstOrDefault();
                                return greenDetails;
                            },
                            splitOn: "AttributesJson",
                            param: new { itemId ,itemTypeId},
                            commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure)).FirstOrDefault();
            
                    case ...
                    default: return null;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My colleague is suggesting that doing this kind of business logic in repository is not a good approach.
So, there is one alternative (at least one I'm aware of) - fetching data into Item Entity (leave the JSON in flat string), and map it to the DTOs on the Service layer (MyProject.Core) either with simple assignment (Option 2.1), which I found not much elegant way, or using Automapper (Option 2.2)

```
namespace MyProject.Data
{
    public class DetailsRepository : IDetailsRepository
    {
        public async Task<Item> GetDetails(int itemId, int itemTypeId)
        {
            using (var connection = _dataAccess.GetConnection())
            {
                return await connection.QuerySingleAsync<Item>("[spGetDetails]", param: new { itemId ,itemTypeId}, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Option 2.1:

```
namespace MyProject.Core.Services
{
    public class DetailsService : IDetailsService
    {
        public async Task<DtoItem> GetDetails(int itemId, int itemTypeId)
        {
            var itemDetailsEntity = await _detailsRepo.GetDetails(int itemId, int itemTypeId);
            switch(itemTypeId){

                case 1:
                    var result = new DtoTypeRed();
                    result.Id= itemDetailsEntity.Id;
                    result.Name = itemDetailsEntity.Name;
                    result.AttributesJson = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<DtoTypeRedAttributes>>(itemDetailsEntity.AttributesJson).FirstOrDefault();
                case ...
            }
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

If this is the way, maybe some factory would be better? (I don't have any yet)

Option 2.2 with Automapper:
The thing is, I read somewhere, that Automapper is not really meant to include the JSON deserialization logic - it should be more "auto"

```
namespace MyProject.Core.Mappings
{
    public class MapperProfiles : Profile
    {
        public MapperProfiles()
        {
            CreateMap<Entities.Item, DTO.Details.DtoTypeRed>()
                .ForMember(dest => dest.AttributesJson, opts => opts.MapFrom(src =>JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<DtoTypeRedAttributes>>(src.AttributesJson, null).FirstOrDefault()));
            (...)
        }
    }
}
```

```
namespace MyProject.Core.Services
{
    public class DetailsService : IDetailsService
    {
        public async Task<DtoItem> GetDetails(int itemId, int itemTypeId)
        {
            var itemDetailsEntity = await _detailsRepo.GetDetails(int itemId, int itemTypeId);
            switch(itemTypeId){
                case 1:
                    return _mapper.Map<DtoTypeRed>(itemDetailsEntity);
                case 2: 
                    return _mapper.Map<DtoTypeGreen>(itemDetailsEntity);
                case ...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I really lack this "architectural" knowledge and experience, so any suggestions would be really appreciated. Maybe some other way I do not see here?

Comment: The first line of your question talks about "the purest" - what do you mean by that?

Comment: @AdrianK I meant: the most compliant with clean architecture rules, elegant and efficient way of doing this, because every approach would do. The question is which one would do it in the best manner?

Comment: Cool.  I'm not an expert on the detailed specifics of "Clean" architecture, but, it's essentials align with what I would call general best practice and principles.  Jakob's answer is a good one in that respect.

Comment: "I need to transfer this data way up to the controller" - does the JSON have to go up to the controller as-is (as JSON)?  If not - why the need for the JSON at all?

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering your software design is rather unusual, I think there's two questions you should ask yourself first:

- You're using a relational DB, but are also using it to store a JSON (as in a NoSQL DB). Is this is a preexisting schema where you don't have any influence on changing it? If not, why are you using this design and not separate tables for the different data structures, as you would normally do in a relational schema? This would also give you the advantages of a relational DB like querying, foreign keys, indexing.
- If you have a controller where you hand out your object anyway, you will probably do this as a JSON, right? Then what would be the point of deserializing it? Can't you just leave the JSON as is?

Apart from that, if you want to stick to your options, I would go with a solution similar to your option 1. Your colleague is right that you don't want to have business logic in a repository, since the responsibilty of a repository is only to store and query data. Business logic in an onion architecture belongs to your service layer. However, if you are only deserializing data from the DB to a structure that is usable to you in your program, then this logic should be in the repository. All you do in this case  is to fetch data and transform it into objects, same thing as an ORM tool would do.

One thing I would change in option 1 though, is to move the switch-case to your service layer, since this is business logic. So:

```
public class DetailsService : IDetailService {
    public async Task<Item> GetDetails(int itemId, int itemTypeId) {
       Item myItem;
       switch(itemTypeId){
          case 1:
             myItem = _repo.getRedItem(itemId);
          // and so on
       }
    }
}
```

Your repository would then have methods for the individual item types. So again, all it does is querying and deserializing data.

On your other two options: the point of DTOs usually is to have separate objects which you can share with other processes (like when sending them out in a controller). This way, changes in the DTO then don't influence changes in your entity and vice versa, as well as you can choose which properties you want to include in your DTO or entity and which not. In your case it seems you are only really using the DTOs in your program and the entities are just there as an intermediate step, which makes it pointless to even have any entity.

Also, using AutoMapper in your scenario only makes the code more complicated, which you can see in your code in `MapperProfiles`, where you probably agree with me that it isn't easy to understand and maintain.

Comment: Thank you very much for this suggestions! 
Answering your questions:
1. Unfortunately, I do not have the influence on what is happening on the DB side. I agree, this is quite unusual case, but apparently it has to be done like this. 
2. Because we'll have to do some processing on that JSON - add/ change some things, in the near future. 
I'm also considering mapping it to some dictionary, if this processing won't be that complex or maybe creating some extension method for custom mapping between them. What would you say? Or this modified Option1 is still better in your opinion?

Comment: Depends on how much operations you have to perform on the data. Usually working with types as much as possible is preferrable, as it avoids errors like typos and gives you advantages like inheritance or making validation easier and more

Answer (score 0):

Jakob's answer is good and I agree with a lot that he says.  To add to that...

The challenge you have is that you want to be as pure to Clean Architecture as possible, but you're constrained by a system where there are two conflicting architectural patterns:

- The "traditional" approach where the data structures are explicit.
- Alternative approach where the data structures are mixed: some data structures are defined by the database (table design) whilst others are structured in the code (JSON) - of which the database has no visibility (to the database it's just a string).

A further complication is at the code level where you have a classic layered architecture with explicitly defined objects and layers, and then you have this mutant JSON thing.

Based on the information do far i wonder if you can use a generic list for the JSON attributes - because your code is taking the JSON and converting it into essentially key-value pairs - at least that's what's suggested by your code:

```
MyProject.Core.DTO.Details.DtoTypeRedAttributes.AttributeOneOne{ get; set; }
```

This says to me that the Controller is getting `AttributeOneOne` which will have a name/key and value inside it.  Whatever consumes this will care about the name/key, but to the rest of your code you just have generic attributes.

I'm also suspicious/curious of the `type` field in the database which you say is 'never returned by the procedure', but you have type specific code? e.g. `DtoTypeRedAttributes`.

Based on all of that, I would simplify things (which still keeps you within Clean):

**Deserializing the JSON into a generic key/value pair:**

- This could happen in either then data access layer or within the DTO itself.
- A straight JSON to Key/Value pair conversion is purely technical and does not affect any business rule, so there's no business rule/logic drivers that influence where that can happen.

**Q:** How expensive is the deserialization?  And are those attributes *always* accessed?  If it's expense, and the attributes aren't always used, then you can use Lazy Load to only trigger the deserialization when it's needed - this would suggest doing it in the DTO, because if you do it in the data access layer you'll get that deserialization penalty every time, regardless.

A potential downside, if you care about it, is that you'll have a DTO with a `private string RawJSONAttributes` property and a `public List<string,string> JSONAttributes` key/value pair property.  I.e. larger memory foot-print, and you'll have to consider consistency (do you care about the private string if someone changes the public values, etc).

**DTO Consolidation**

If the DTO's can get away with only providing a generic list of key/value pairs, then based on what else you've said so far, I don't see why you have separate red,green,blue code.  One DTO would do it.

If you do need separate types then yes, some sort of factory would probably be a good approach.

- The Data Access code could return "generic" DTOs (like WidgetInfo, in my diagram) up to the consuming logic.
- That logic (which did the DTO conversion) would probably shield the consumers / Controllers above, so that they only saw BlueWidget, RedWidget (etc) DTOs and not the generic one.

**Summary**

The diagram shows how I would typically do this (consuming Controllers not shown), assuming generic DTO's were ok.  Let me know if I need to diagram out the other approach (conversion of generic WidgetInfo to BlueWidget/RedWidget DTOs).

Note that the DTO has a public property for the attributes (list of key/value pairs); it would also have a private string for the RawJSONAttributes if you wanted to take the Lazy Load approach in the DTO.

[image]